# C# HTMLAgilityPack count tr elements of first table

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I am using the HTMLAgilityPack for several times.
But I have no solution for my following problem:

```
<table class="tableClass">
  <thead>...</thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>...</tr>
    <tr>...</tr>
    <tr>...</tr>
    <tr>...</tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table class="tableClass">
  <thead>...</thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>...</tr>
    <tr>...</tr>
    <tr>...</tr>
    <tr>...</tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

So, this is the HTML code.

I can find the first "tableClass" by this:

```
HtmlNode node= htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table[@class='tableClass'][1]");
```

Then, I want to count the  elements within the first table.

```
foreach (HtmlNode tableRow in node.SelectNodes("//tbody//tr"))
 {
     size = size + 1;
 }
```

The result is always 8 instead of 4.

Please help :/

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Do not use `//` in your XPath if you want to get subnodes of a specific node. use `.//` instead. do not precede a subnode in your XPath with `//`:

```
var trNodes=node.SelectNodes(".//tr");
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query for the `tr` tags is not correct. You are starting it with double slashes, which means, that query will be executed on whole document. If you need to query subnodes, then you need to remove that double slashes from your query

```
node.SelectNodes("tbody//tr")
```

Also, you can get count you needed by just one line of code

```
htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[@class='tableClass'][1]//tbody//tr").Count
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me: node.SelectNodes("tbody//tr"). Your second suggestion doesn't work. The result is 8, too.

Comment: It is working, I just tested it on the html from your question